# How to update marker positions in a scatter mapbox?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to display live location data on a mapbox scatter plot. In order to mimic new data received from the server the callback moves all points every 3 seconds:

```py
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

px.set_mapbox_access_token(open(".mapbox_token").read())
df = px.data.carshare()

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='map', animate=True),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=3000,
    )
])


@app.callback(Output('map', 'figure'), [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_map(n):
    df['centroid_lon'] += 0.01
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="centroid_lat", lon="centroid_lon")

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

While the labels are correctly changing their location, the markers are stuck at their original positions.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFetj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around by having two callbacks.
my html looks like this dbc.Col > dcc.Graph(figure = fig)

```
@app.callback(
    Output('graph-id','figure'),

    Input('control-id', 'n_clicks')
)
def update_func(scatter_map_fig):
    return go.Figure
```

The second callback returns a new graph component with the updated information of the figure

```
@app.callback(
    Output('col-id','children'),

    Input('graph-id', 'figure'),

    State('date_range','start_date'),
    State('date_range','end_date'),
)
def update_func_2(scatter_map_fig):
    scatter_fig = go.Figure()
    scatter_fig.update_layout(...)
    ... (put your figure logic here)
    return dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
```

It is a bit janky but it works until there's a better solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tested the method using html.Div instead of dbc.Col, it works! the idea was to use click control to reset an empty go.Figure() object, then this object as Input will trigger the 2nd callback that creates a new Figure in dcc.Graph() and replace the children... Brilliant! (don't forget to put "id=graph_id" in the dcc.Graph.)